# Storing sensitive data in mongodb/node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, security, express

I am working on a project which requires my web app to collect sensitive information from users (e.g. photo of driver's license.) This is done via a file upload on Angular and I was planning on storing the images as a binary array in MongoDB. I was also considering storing the images directly on the server using node.js (busbuy, or fs I believe) and storing a reference of the image in the server (API points have implemented proper access-controlled in both cases)  The problem is.. I don't know how secure either approach would be.

Like passwords, I don't believe storing "plain/raw" image of sensitive data (DL, SSN) is considered in any sense secure.

What is an approach to secure the storage of sensitive images on a server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store the images into database, and **secure the database**. MongoDB provides couple of ways to protect its data. For example, enable TLS/SSL connection between database and server, authenticate all clients before connection established, add access control to images collection.

Here are some useful references:
[How to Install and Secure MongoDB](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04#part-two-securing-mongodb)
[MongoDB security documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/security/)

Comment: There is no need to encrypt the images on the database? I can restrict access control for the users on the client, and "hackers" trying to pen my server. Who I cannot control is the database admin who is maintaining the server (me for now, but not for long..) Additionally, I had a preconceived notion that we need to encrypt our user's stored data in the db somehow (so in the database all we see is hashes, secret is hidden)  @MarkoCen Maybe if I give you more scope on the project you might be able to understand how strong we require our security?

Comment: I understood your point. There are two layers of security. The security I mentioned in this answer is on database layer, more like an infrastructure security, and image encryption you mentioned is on data layer. For encryption data itself, there are many articles out there, just google 'encrypt data nodejs'. But for my experiences, securing database is much more important than securing data. Hackers can destroy unprotected database even without trying steal the data.

Comment: is there a way to encrypt customer data, and only allow a designated user (by ID) to access it?